# Experimenting with Xen on already running Debian without LVM

Tags: debian, lvm, xen

A co-worker of mine was telling me about using Xen for virtualizing systems on Debian, and it peaked my interest. I looked up the instructions on [Debian's Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Xen) regarding installation.

I already have a running system of Debian, and do not wish to repartition my hard drives (setup in RAID using `mdadm`), and the installation wiki says to use LVM. My question is, **is this a requirement** or just a suggestion? Can I get away with installing Xen without repartitioning my system?

Comment: A tip: You can repartition a mirror on a tricky way: break off a side of the mirror, partition it as you wish, reboot into that, and then resync.

Comment: @PeterHorvath RAID 10, so I'd have to cut out two drives... I feel in my gut that wouldn't be too safe. I have backups, but I'd prefer not to "need" them

Comment: Tip2: raid disks can have also partitions, although it is not a really well-known feature. Google for the "kpartx" tool, it explains everything.

Comment: Tip3: AFAIK there is some like a xen-based vm-host sharing fs solution or similar, I never used that but as I can remember, there is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, lvm is not required to use xen, just strongly recommended.  You can use regular disk files to back the virtual disks assigned to the domUs, either as raw images, or qcow2.  You probably want qcow2.

On Debian simply installing the xen packages should automatically add extra entries to your grub menu allowing you to choose to boot using xen.  This will boot your existing kernel under the xen hypervisor and it should operate just as it does normally, with the exception that you will then be able to use the xen commands to carve off some ram to create a new domain, provide it with a virtual disk, and boot it up.

Comment: Briefly looking at Wikipedia about qcow2, that's just using a .IMG file as a hard disk, then my VMs (domains) would partition it how they want. Is that correct?

Comment: @CanadianLuke, yes, that is correct.  Depending on how you configured it, the guest will see the image file as a disk, either /dev/xvda ( for an efficient xen paravirtual disk ), or /dev/sda ( for a fully emulated IDE or SCSI disk ).

Comment: Well then, I'm going to give this a try! Thanks